How to decode data from shred?
I found this shred doc:
https://github.com/solana-foundation/specs/blob/main/p2p/shred.md#shred-payload-construction. Jito ShredStream service offers traders to subscribe shred data and I believe these shred data is the same thing with Solana shred data,
Is there any way I can decode the Solana shred data into readable transaction?
